# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm doing a CRUD with redux. The application has a form with a username, and then a screen to create, view, edit and delete posts and I'm doing the editing part. However, when I use `array.find()` to traverse the array and look for each post, I'm getting this error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')

I will leave the codes below.

**EditScreen:**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import '../_assets/modal.css';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

import {editPost} from '../redux/postsslice';

function EditModal({ closeModal}) {

    const { pathname } = useLocation();
    const postId = pathname.replace("/edit-post/", "")
    const post  = useSelector((state) => state.posts.find((post) => post.id === postId))
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const navigation = useNavigate();

    const [title, setTitle] = useState(post.title)
    const [content, setContent] = useState(post.content)

    

    const onTitleChanged = e => setTitle(e.target.value)
    const onContentChanged = e => setContent(e.target.value)

    const onSavePostClicked = (e) => {
        if (title && content) {
            dispatch(editPost({id: postId, title, content}))
        }
           
    }


    return (
        <div className="modalBackground">
            <div className="modalContainer">
                <div className="title"><h1>Edit item</h1></div>
                <h2>Title</h2>
                <form>
                <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Hello World"
              name="name"
              value={title}
              onChange={onTitleChanged}
            ></input>
            <h2>Content</h2>
            <textarea
              placeholder="Content"
              name="content"
              value={content}
              onChange={onContentChanged}
            ></textarea>
                
                    <button onClick={onSavePostClicked}>SAVE</button></form>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default EditModal
```

**mainscreen:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "../_assets/App.css";
import "../_assets/mainscreen.css";
import { MdDeleteForever } from "react-icons/md";
import { FiEdit } from "react-icons/fi";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { addPost } from '../redux/postsslice'
import {nanoid} from 'nanoid'

import Modal from "../components/modal.jsx";
import EditModal from '../components/editmodal.jsx';

function MainScreen() {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user)
const posts = useSelector((state) => state.loadPosts)

  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");
  const [buttonGreyOut, setButtonGreyOut] = useState("#cccccc");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (title && content !== "") {
      setButtonGreyOut("black");
    } else {
      setButtonGreyOut("#cccccc");
    }
  },[title, content]);

  const handleSubmitSendPost = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(
      addPost({
        id: nanoid(),
        title,
        content
      })
    )
    setTitle('')
    setContent('')
  };

  const handleChangeTitle = (text) => {
    setTitle(text);
  };

  const handleChangeContent = (text) => {
    setContent(text);
  };

  const [openEditModal, setOpenEditModal] = useState();
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState();

  if (user === '') {
    return <Navigate to="/" />
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="containerMainScreen">
        {openModal && <Modal closeModal={setOpenModal} />}
        {openEditModal && <EditModal closeModal={setOpenEditModal} />}
        <div className="bar">
          <h1>Codeleap</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="boxPost">
          <h2 style={{ fontWeight: 700 }}>What's on your mind?</h2>
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmitSendPost}>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Hello World"
              name="name"
              value={title}
              onChange={(e) => handleChangeTitle(e.target.value)}
            ></input>
            <h2>Content</h2>
            <textarea
              placeholder="Content"
              name="content"
              value={content}
              onChange={(e) => handleChangeContent(e.target.value)}
            ></textarea>
            <button
              className="createButton"
              type="submit"
              style={{ backgroundColor: buttonGreyOut }}
              disabled={!title || !content}
            >
              CREATE
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
  
        {posts.map((post) => (
          <div className="boxPost" key={post.id}>
            <div className="bar">
              <h1>{post.title}</h1>
              <MdDeleteForever
                className="icon"
                onClick={() => {
                  setOpenModal(true);
                }}
              />
              <FiEdit
                onClick={() => {
                  setOpenEditModal(true);
                }}
                style={{ color: "white", fontSize: "45px", paddingLeft: "23px" }}
              />
            </div>
            <div id="postowner">
                <h3>@{user}</h3>
              <br></br>
              <textarea style={{ border: "none" }}>{post.content}</textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  
  }export default MainScreen;
```

**postSlice:**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const postsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "posts",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    addPost (state, action) {
      state.push(action.payload); // modifies the draft state.
    },
  editPost(state, action) {
    const { id, title, content } = action.payload;
    const existingPost = state.find((post) => post.id === id);
    if (existingPost) {
      existingPost.title = title
      existingPost.content = content
    }
  }
}
});

export const { addPost, editPost } = postsSlice.actions

export default postsSlice
```

**editModal.js (edit page)**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import '../_assets/modal.css';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

import {editPost} from '../redux/postsslice';

export function EditModal({ closeModal}) {

    const { pathname } = useLocation();
    const postId = parseInt(pathname.replace("edit-post/", ""))
    const post = useSelector((state) => state.loadPosts.find((post) => post.id === postId))
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const navigation = useNavigate();

    

    const [title, setTitle] = useState(post.title)
    const [content, setContent] = useState(post.content)

    

    const onTitleChanged = e => setTitle(e.target.value)
    const onContentChanged = e => setContent(e.target.value)

    const onSavePostClicked = (e) => {
        if (title && content) {
            dispatch(editPost({id: postId, title, content}))
        }
           
    }


    return (
        <div className="modalBackground">
            <div className="modalContainer">
                <div className="title"><h1>Edit item</h1></div>
                <h2>Title</h2>
                <form>
                <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Hello World"
              name="name"
              value={title}
              onChange={onTitleChanged}
            ></input>
            <h2>Content</h2>
            <textarea
              placeholder="Content"
              name="content"
              value={content}
              onChange={onContentChanged}
            ></textarea>
                
                    <button onClick={onSavePostClicked}>SAVE</button></form>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default EditModal
```

**store.js:**

```
 import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
  import userSlice from './userslice';
  import postsSlice from './postsslice'

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        user: userSlice.reducer,
        loadPosts: postsSlice.reducer

    },
  })

  export default store
```

**signup page:**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import "../_assets/signup.css";
import "../_assets/App.css";
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import userSlice from '../redux/userslice';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Signup() {

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [name, setName] = useState('')

  const [buttonGrey, setButtonGrey] = useState('#cccccc')



  useEffect(() => {


      if (name!== '') {
          
          setButtonGrey("black")
      }  

      else {
        setButtonGrey('#cccccc')
        
      }
  }, [name])

  

  const handleSubmitForm= (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch(userSlice.actions.saveUser(name))
    navigate("/main")
  }
  
  const handleChangeName = (text) => {
    setName(text)
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="LoginBox">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmitForm}>
        <h2>Welcome to codeleap network</h2>
        <text>Please enter your username</text>
        <input type="text" name="name" value={name} onChange = {e => handleChangeName(e.target.value)}  placeholder="Jane Doe"  />
        <div className="button">
        <button type="submit" style={{backgroundColor: buttonGrey}}  disabled={!name} >
          ENTER
        </button>

        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Signup;
```

Comment: Which specific `.find` usage is the issue? You've listed two, one in the `editPost` reducer and the other in a `useSelector` hook. The one in the reducer seems fine (*barring any other actions you've not listed that aren't maintaining your state invariant*) so I'll assume it's the `state.posts.find` in the selector function. Can you share how you configure your store and combine your reducers so we've a clearer picture of your state shape?

Comment: I added the store and some more code to the post. ... I'm having a lot of difficulties to implement the edit and delete part of the CRUD.

Comment: I see, so the posts state is `state.loadPosts`, so in `EditModal` it should be `const post  = useSelector((state) => state.loadPosts.find((post) => post.id === postId))` I believe.

Comment: it's already the way you said

Comment: That error disappeared, but then this one appeared: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')

Comment: I see, you added a second `EditModal` snippet with the correct state access. And this isn't working?

Comment: I think I'm missing something very specific because I've compared my code to other similar CRUDs and it looks pretty similar

Comment: It's not working, when I click on the icon that opens editmodal, it gives me the error I mentioned: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')

Comment: I also tried accessing by title instead of id, putting it in editmodal: const post = useSelector((state) => state.loadPosts.find((post) => post.title === title)) and that in postslice: const existingPost = state.loadPosts.find((post) => post.title === title); but it gives me this error this time: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'title' before initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the state shape:

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userSlice.reducer,
    loadPosts: postsSlice.reducer

  },
});
```

Then the path to the posts state is `state.loadPosts`, so the selector in `EditModal` should be:

```
const post  = useSelector((state) => state.loadPosts.find(
  (post) => post.id === postId),
);
```

The error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')` is closely related to this line of code. If `state.loadPosts` is an empty array ***or*** there are not matching posts by `id`, then `.find` returns undefined.

```
const [title, setTitle] = useState(post.title); // <-- throws error on undefined post
const [content, setContent] = useState(post.content); // <-- throws error on undefined post
```

A quick fix could be to use the Optional Chaining operator

```
const [title, setTitle] = useState(post?.title);
const [content, setContent] = useState(post?.content);
```

but this only sets the initial state. If there is no matching post to edit then there's no point in rendering the editing UI. At this point you should render some fallback UI or navigate back, etc...

Comment: It worked by adding the "?", thanks!. Now it opens the edit modal, but it is showing an empty title and content (when it should show the content of the post I want to edit) and when I click OK adding any random value to the title and content, it goes back to the signup page . Is this route related?

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you meant by "if there is no matching post to edit". I can only click on the edit icon for a post that already exists. Sorry if I got something wrong

Comment: @HeitorKenzou Either route param related, (`"/edit-post/:id"`) or the fact that you are likely comparing a string type value to a number type value with strict equality, i.e. `"5" === 5` is false.

Comment: @HeitorKenzou Ah, by "no matching post by id" I meant that you are getting the matching id from the URL, so it could potentially be a value you haven't explicitly linked from.

Comment: you mean in this line (comparing string to number)?     if (existingPost) {
      existingPost.title = title
      existingPost.content = content

Comment: @HeitorKenzou No, everything I've referred to so far is in the `EditModal` component. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239021/discussion-between-heitor-kenzou-and-drew-reese).